# Add and remove the css style on OnInit, OnDestroy

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I created a component for preview file `audio` , `video` , and I am  using the material dialog for this.

I need to when dialog I open, the background is transparent.

I am using this code in `scss` component:

```
::ng-deep .mat-dialog-container {
    background-color: transparent !important;
  }
```

it does in all dialog but I need to use just for dialog in this component.

in next step I try to use this code to use this style just for this component :

```
@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})

export class StyleService {
    private stylesMap: Map<any, Node> = new Map();
    private host: Node;

    constructor() {
        this.host = document.head;
    }

    private createStyleNode(content: string): Node {
        const styleEl = document.createElement('style');
        styleEl.textContent = content;
        return styleEl;
    }

    addStyle(key: any, style: string): void {
        const styleEl = this.createStyleNode(style);
        this.stylesMap.set(key, styleEl);
        this.host.appendChild(styleEl);
    }

    removeStyle(key: any): void {
        console.log('in')
        const styleEl = this.stylesMap.get(key);
        console.log(styleEl);
        if (styleEl) {
            this.stylesMap.delete(key);
            this.host.removeChild(styleEl);
        }
    }
}
```

and use it in component in this way :

```js
constructor(private styleService: StyleService) {}

ngOnInit(): void {
  this.styleService.addStyle('transparent-dialog-theme', require('../../them/dialogStyle.scss'));
}

ngOnDestroy(): void {
  this.styleService.removeStyle('transparent-dialog-theme');
}
```

but it does not work for me ( no transparent dialog for this component).

What's the problem? how can I solve this problem?

Comment: Did you console the output of `require('../../them/dialogStyle.scss')` ?

Comment: @AdarshMohan it show `undefined`

Comment: Thought so. see [this](https://github.com/cloudinary/cloudinary_angular/issues/69).. I think you were trying to get the file contents.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/learnprogramming/comments/9735g2/angular_6_typescript_read_content_from_file_in/) can help you.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to apply specific style to backdrop of a dialog in any particular case, you can add class to the backdrop with the configuration.

for example -

```
let dialogRef = this.dialog.open(ExampleDialogComponent, {
      width: '250px',
      data: { name: this.name, animal: this.animal },
      backdropClass: 'dialog-bg-trans'
    });
```

and in your global style you can add that style -

```
.dialog-bg-trans {
  background-color: transparent;
}
```

You can provide this config at the place only where you want the behavior, not at other places.

Please refer this - https://stackblitz.com/edit/ab-angular-mat-dialog-bg-color?file=app%2Fexample%2Fexample.component.ts

Hope it would be helpful.

Comment: i need to transparent `::ng-deep .mat-dialog-container {
    background-color: transparent !important;
  }`

Comment: If you have to use ::ng-deep you can try applying it with class cdk-overlay-backdrop  to make backdrop transparent -

      ::ng-deep .cdk-overlay-backdrop{
        background-color: transparent;
      }

Comment: @kianousjdortaj I tried with your approach - adding style to head & removing it on destroy. It looks like its working fine - https://stackblitz.com/edit/ab-angular-mat-dialog-bg-color-with-style-added-head?file=app%2Fexample%2Fexample.component.ts 

Only difference is I have added style content as const rather than require and using class cdk-overlay-backdrop . I have not used require in Angular, rather I think import is common. may be you can try with import('...').then(val => { addStyle }).